# Error: Creating a list in R and error message isn't specific enough to know what part is wrong

Tags: r, list

I'm trying to create a list that does:

- Get the total number of readings
- A vector containing: The min & max
- The mean reading at site 2

```
data_summary = list(length(sensor.clean),list(max(sensor.clean),min(sensor.clean)),
                    mean(sensor.clean$value[sensor.clean$siteid==2]))
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

I do not know what part of the list it's referring to.

Comment: If `sensor.clean` is a `data.frame`, the functions may not work as it expects to work on `vector`.  If you need to get `max` , `min` of all the elements, `max(unlist(sensor.clean))` and `min(unlist(sensor.clean))`

Comment: Thanks, it worked!! what does unlisting do that makes it work?

Comment: I posted a solution with the probable cause.  Based on the error, it could be that you have some `non-numeric` columns i.e. `factor` class.  Please check the `str(sensor.clean)` assuming it is a `data.frame`

Answer (score 0):

If we need the `max/min` of the entire dataset, make sure that it is applied on `numeric` columns

```
i1 <- sapply(sensor.clean, is.numeric)
mx <- max(sensor.clean[i1])
mn <- min(sensor.clean[i1])
```

and use that in `list` creation

```
list(ncol(sensor.clean), list(mx, mn), 
          mean(sensor.clean$value[sensor.clean$siteid==2]))
```

---

here the 'sensor.clean' object `class` is not clear.  If it is a `data.frame`, the `min` and `max` should work.

```
max(data.frame(col1 = 1:3, col2 = 3:5))
#[1] 5
```

But, if it is a `list`, it wouldn't

```
max(list(col1 = 1:3, col2 = 3:5))
```

> Error in max(list(col1 = 1:3, col2 = 3:5)) :    invalid 'type' (list)
>   of argument

For that case, we need to `unlist`

```
max(unlist(list(col1 = 1:3, col2 = 3:5)))
#[1] 5
```

---

However, based on the error message, it seems that the data is `data.frame`, and it can have more than one `class`

```
d1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:3, col2 = letters[1:3], col3 = rnorm(3))
max(d1)
```

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :    only defined on a data frame with all
>   numeric variables

So, here we need to subset the `numeric` columns

```
max(d1[sapply(d1, is.numeric)])
#[1] 3
```